# How can I visually format JSON data (programmatically)?

Tags: asp.net, json, formatting

I'm working with big blobs of JSON. These blobs change slightly over time and a revision history is kept. I'd really like to be able to do a visual diff on them, but my problem is they're being stored without any formatting at all - everything is on one line, so that makes it a little hard to see what changed.

Is there a good way to programatically format them ala http://jsonformat.com/ or http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx to deserialize/serialize back with formating.

Answer (score 2):

If Python is one of the languages that you can use:

```
>>> j='{ "tstr" : "xxx", "tarrr" : [ "a0", "a1" ] }'
>>> import json
>>> a=json.loads(j)
>>> print json.dumps(a, indent = 4, sort_keys=True);
{
    "tarrr": [
        "a0", 
        "a1"
    ], 
    "tstr": "xxx"
}
```

Would this help?

EDIT:

Here's a Python script that takes a single valid JSON object in its standard input and outputs its formatted version in its standard output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import sys

print json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin), indent = 4, sort_keys = True)
```

Usage example on Linux:

```
$ echo '{ "tstr" : "xxx", "tarrr" : [ "a0", "a1" ] }' | ./json-format.py 
{
    "tarrr": [
        "a0", 
        "a1"
    ], 
    "tstr": "xxx"
}
```

And [here](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) is the documentation for the Python JSON module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how feasible this will be given the context of the app in question (asp.net) but I'm going to look into it further to see what my options are. (also added asp.net tag to question to clarify technology stack - should have done that in the first place!)

Comment: Well, I got this working with my JSON data using IronPython and calling it from C# - now to see if all this craziness is something I can actually reasonably integrate/distribute as a plug-in to the target application.

Comment: @Ian Robinson: well, having an embedded Python interpretter can be helpful for more things in the future, but it *does* sound somewhat crazy at the moment... I wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Jayrock JSON library for .Net](http://jayrock.berlios.de/#what-is)?

[Json.org](http://www.json.org/) also lists other potential libraries for ASP and C# at the bottom of the page.